# Process "System" needs 100% Harddrive input/output

Tags: windows-8, task-manager

I'm on Windows 8 and in my Task-Manager I see that the process "System" needs 100% of my IO capacity. What is the reason or how to find out what exactly the reason is? It slows down my PC.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run [Resource Monitor](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/use-resource-monitor-to-monitor-storage-performance/4233), go to the Disk tab and look which files the System/Kernel reads or writes.

[image]